# Deserialize JSON and save model in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I have a JSON file which needs to be deserialized using the two classes below: Car and Brand. When I load the files individually, how do I map Car.Brand to Brand?
The JSON file includes the Car.Brand as "Tesla"  whereas the JSON file Brand has Brand.Name as Tesla and an ID.

How do I solve the mapping issue?

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Current code is insufficient:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"cars.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    cars = (List<Car>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(List<Car>));
}
```

car.json

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Polo",
        "Brand": "Volkswagen"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "328",
        "Brand": "BMW"
    },
}]
```

brand.json

```
[{
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Volkswagen"
    },
    {
        "Id": 9,
        "Name": "BMW"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Since you're using Entity Framework, why not save the data in a database instead of a flat json file?

Comment: I indeed want to retrieve the data from a JSON file and save it to the EF database. But in order to do that I need to retrieve it the right way (include the links to Brand)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom JsonConverter to deserialize the car object using a brands Dictionary.

```
public class CustomCarConverter : JsonConverter<Car>
{
    Dictionary<string, Brand> _brands;

    public CustomCarConverter(Dictionary<string, Brand> brands)
    {
        _brands = brands;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Car value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override Car ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Car existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return new Car()
        {
            Id = obj.GetValue("Id").Value<int>(),
            Name = obj.GetValue("Name").Value<string>(),
            Brand = _brands[obj.GetValue("Brand").Value<string>()]
        };
    }
}
```

Deserialize call:

```
var brands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Brand>>(brandsJSON);
var brandsByName = brands.ToDictionary(item => item.Name, item => item);
var cars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Car>>(carsJSON, new CustomCarConverter(brandsByName));
//Save to DB
```

Additionally, the JSON strings you posted are invalid as they have an additional `}`.

Comment: Do you know what is going wrong here? It's not able to convert Model.Car to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.

var cars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Car>>(file, new CustomCarConverter<Car>(brandsByName));

I've defined the converter as: 
    public class CustomCarConverter<T> : JsonConverter
        where T : class, new()

Comment: @ErrorAgain What is the exception?